# JavaScript function not being recognized as a function using prompt/alert

Tags: javascript, function, alert, prompt

I am trying to write a program that will generate a short and simple description for real estate properties. I have (array) word banks with adjectives, prompts for inputs with specific details (square footage, # of bedrooms etc), two functions with else if statements that will generate a specific sentences, and then a "description" variable that joins these sentences, prompted inputs and word bank adjectives together.

I am having trouble calling the result of the functions in the last description variable. I stored the functions as a variable with the variable it is assessing (location and walkDist) within it. When I run this program it doesn't give me the prompts for these variables and prints out the code of the functions instead of the sentence I want it to.

When I take location and walkDist out of the functions I get the prompt but the webpage returns an error after I input a 0,1,2.

The function isn't being recognized as a function for some reason. Is there something I am missing or is there a better way to store the else if without a function for this use case?

```
    let wordBank1 = ['Breathtaking', 'Incredible', 'Beautiful', 'Stunning', 'Incredible', 'Magnificent']
let wb1Selector = wordBank1[Math.floor(Math.random()*wordBank1.length)]
let wordBank2 = ['gorgeous', 'panoramic', 'expansive', 'compelling', 'immaculate']
let wb2Selector = wordBank2[Math.floor(Math.random()*wordBank2.length)]

let sqFoot = prompt(alert('how many square feet?'))
let bedRoom = prompt(alert('how many bedrooms?'))
let bathRoom = prompt(alert('how many bathrooms?'))
let lotSize = prompt(alert('how big is the lot size?'))

// when run program is not recognizing bayBeach and walkingDistance as functions
var location = prompt(alert('if this is on beach block enter a 1, if this is a bayfront enter a 2, if it is neither enter a 0'))
let bayBeach = function(location) {
  if (location == 1) {
    return 'only a block from the beach, this home boasts of ' + wb2Selector + ' views.'
  } else if (location == 2) {
    return 'situated on the bay, this property offers ' + wb2Selector + ' views.'
  }
}

var walkDist = prompt(alert('if this home is between 90th and 110th street enter a 1, if it is above 40th street enter a 2, otherwise enter a 0'))
let walkingDistance = function(walkDist) {
  if (walkDist == 1) {
    return 'Enjoy your vacation within walking distance of the pizza joints and novelty shops of downtown Stone Harbor.'
  } else if (walkDist == 2) {
    return 'Your rental will keep you within a short walk of everything that downtown Avalon has to offer.'
  } else {
    return 'Get everywhere you need on your vacation with a walk to the beach and a bike ride downtown.'
  }
}

let description1 = wb1Selector + ' ' + sqFoot + ' square foot property with ' + bedRoom  + ' bedrooms and ' + bathRoom + ' bathrooms. ' + bayBeach + ' '
 + walkingDistance

 alert(description1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that although you've defined the functions, but you need to *call* the functions instead of just referring to them by name. That is, instead of `bayBeach` you need to have `bayBeach(loc)`. This tells JS to run the function using `loc` as the input.

In my snippet I've changed `location` to `loc` because `location` is a global name in JS (referring to the page location) and the compiler doesn't want it re-declared.

Also, you don't need to alert inside a prompt, this just brings up two separate dialog boxes.

```js
let wordBank1 = ['Breathtaking', 'Incredible', 'Beautiful', 'Stunning', 'Incredible', 'Magnificent'];
let wb1Selector = wordBank1[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordBank1.length)];
let wordBank2 = ['gorgeous', 'panoramic', 'expansive', 'compelling', 'immaculate'];
let wb2Selector = wordBank2[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordBank2.length)];

let sqFoot = prompt('how many square feet?');
let bedRoom = prompt('how many bedrooms?');
let bathRoom = prompt('how many bathrooms?');
let lotSize = prompt('how big is the lot size?');
let loc = prompt('if this is on beach block enter a 1, if this is a bayfront enter a 2, if it is neither enter a 0');
let walkDist = prompt('if this home is between 90th and 110th street enter a 1, if it is above 40th street enter a 2, otherwise enter a 0');

let bayBeach = function (location) {
  if (location == 1) {
    return 'only a block from the beach, this home boasts of ' + wb2Selector + ' views.'
  } else if (location == 2) {
    return 'situated on the bay, this property offers ' + wb2Selector + ' views.'
  }
}

let walkingDistance = function(walkDist) {
  if (walkDist == 1) {
    return 'Enjoy your vacation within walking distance of the pizza joints and novelty shops of downtown Stone Harbor.'
  } else if (walkDist == 2) {
    return 'Your rental will keep you within a short walk of everything that downtown Avalon has to offer.'
  } else {
    return 'Get everywhere you need on your vacation with a walk to the beach and a bike ride downtown.'
  }
}

let description1 = wb1Selector + ' ' + sqFoot + ' square foot property with ' + bedRoom + ' bedrooms and ' + bathRoom + ' bathrooms. ' + bayBeach(loc) + ' ' +
  walkingDistance(walkDist)

alert(description1)
```

Comment: worked like a charm thank you, and thanks for the heads up on the prompt/alert redundancy, was something I needed to unlearn

Answer (score -1):

```js
 let wordBank1 = ['Breathtaking', 'Incredible', 'Beautiful', 'Stunning', 'Incredible', 'Magnificent']
let wb1Selector = wordBank1[Math.floor(Math.random()*wordBank1.length)]
let wordBank2 = ['gorgeous', 'panoramic', 'expansive', 'compelling', 'immaculate']
let wb2Selector = wordBank2[Math.floor(Math.random()*wordBank2.length)]

let sqFoot = prompt(alert('how many square feet?'))
let bedRoom = prompt(alert('how many bedrooms?'))
let bathRoom = prompt(alert('how many bathrooms?'))
let lotSize = prompt(alert('how big is the lot size?'))

// when run program is not recognizing bayBeach and walkingDistance as functions
var location = prompt(alert('if this is on beach block enter a 1, if this is a bayfront enter a 2, if it is neither enter a 0'))
let bayBeach = function(location) {
  if (location == 1) {
    return 'only a block from the beach, this home boasts of ' + wb2Selector + ' views.'
  } else if (location == 2) {
    return 'situated on the bay, this property offers ' + wb2Selector + ' views.'
  }
}

var walkDist = prompt(alert('if this home is between 90th and 110th street enter a 1, if it is above 40th street enter a 2, otherwise enter a 0'))
let walkingDistance = function(walkDist) {
  if (walkDist == 1) {
    return 'Enjoy your vacation within walking distance of the pizza joints and novelty shops of downtown Stone Harbor.'
  } else if (walkDist == 2) {
    return 'Your rental will keep you within a short walk of everything that downtown Avalon has to offer.'
  } else {
    return 'Get everywhere you need on your vacation with a walk to the beach and a bike ride downtown.'
  }
}

let description1 = wb1Selector + ' ' + sqFoot + ' square foot property with ' + bedRoom  + ' bedrooms and ' + bathRoom + ' bathrooms. ' + bayBeach(location) + ' '
 + walkingDistance(walkDist)

 alert(description1)
```